# New operation in hook_access()

Tags: drupal, drupal-permissions

Is it possible to define a new operation for a node access?

As I know, the operations for a node that are used in `hook_access()` are:

- create
- delete
- update
- view

I have a custom content type for which I need another operation, such as "suggest."

Answer (score 1):

short answer is NO as node_access() who is responsible to call hook_access() [does a check 
on the $op parameter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_access/6)

> if (!$node || !in_array($op,
>   array('view', 'update', 'delete',
>   'create'), TRUE)) {
>       return FALSE;   }

you can attach some extra info to the node object in your suggest() function - hopefully called before node_access() - then check these extra informations in your hook_access() and return TRUE/FALSE according.

another option consists in hardcode permission checks into the suggest() action itself without messing around with hook_access.